# How to fill missing values in pandas series with 1 if and only if the last and next non missing value is 1

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas series with `0`, `1` and `np.nan` values only:

```
pd.Series([0, np.nan, np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 
np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1])
```

I'd like to fill missing values, but my logic is to replace `np.nan` value with 1 if and only if the previous and next non-missing values are 1 as well, otherwise 0. So the expected output is:

```
pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Following your prescription for imputing, the first and the last elements are always `0` if need to be imputed. You can run a check on `vals = ds.values` through all indexes `for i in range(1, len(vals)-1)` on `vals[i-1]*vals[i+1] == 1`, setting `vals[i]=1` and `0` otherwise. When done, reassign to Series and impute `ds.fillna(0)` for first and last values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in built method that does that you would have to write your own code for this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([0, np.nan, np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan,
               np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1])

vals = s.values.tolist()
look_left = [-1] * len(vals)
look_right = [-1] * len(vals)

for i in range(2):
    check = vals if i == 0 else vals[::-1]
    arr = look_left if i == 0 else look_right
    prev_seen = None
    for i, elem in enumerate(check):
        if elem in [0, 1]:
            arr[i] = elem
            prev_seen = elem
        else:
            arr[i] = prev_seen

look_right = look_right[::-1]

for i in range(len(vals)):

    if np.isnan(vals[i]):
        vals[i] = 1 if look_right[i] == 1 and look_left[i] == 1 else  0

s = pd.Series(vals)
print(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

Fill a value forward with `fillna`.

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Note that that results in inputing `1` after third `1` (in original data) while it should be `0`.

Comment: I used your data as is and checked the results. Do you mean that the data you want is different?

Comment: It is different. Check the 15th element (at index 14).

Comment: Your fifteenth is a NaN, and since the fourteenth is a 1, the fifteenth is a 1 with `method='ffill'`.

Comment: Exactly. And it should be 0 according to my expected output. So `ffill` isn't the answer here.